# Use a date range to create new variable

Tags: python, pandas

I have created a date range using the following:

```
fabi_dte_fwd   = pd.date_range(start='7/23/2019', periods=8, freq='1W-Fri')
fabi_dte_bwd   = pd.date_range(start='7/23/2019', periods=8, freq='-1W-Fri')
fabi_dte_all   = set(fabi_dte_fwd).union(set(fabi_dte_bwd))
fabi_dte       = pd.DataFrame(fabi_dte_all)
```

Now I'd like to create a new variable in the dataframe that basically is something like:

```
fabi_dte['WEEK'] = 'WEEK1' for the first week in the range
fabi_dte['WEEK'] = 'WEEK2' for the second week in the range..etc etc.
```

More generally, do I use list comprehension for this type of thing? I am pretty new to Python.

Comment: What do you want to save exactly in this variable? `fabi_dte` will be a `pandas.core.series.Series` after your operations, but the second code block makes no sense at all.

Comment: all i wanted was a new variable based on the date, where the first date gets a value of "Week1", the following week gets a value of "Week2".  I think I solved it with the following: fabi_dte['WEEK']  = fabi_dte[0].rank(ascending=1, method='min')